# Facebook Messenger (Python) two different results same user

Tags: python, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, chatbot

Currently I am building a Facebook Messenger bot using this library [PyMessenger](https://github.com/davidchua/pymessenger) and I am encountering a strange behavior.

The purpose of my silly bot is to simply append a number 1 to a list every time the user writes a message, and then return the length of the list.

My problem is that the value returned is wrong.The bot is acting as if it has two different lists for the same user. For example, after writing one message, the output should be 1, and after writing the second message the output should be 2. Now, sometimes after I write a third message the output is 1, instead of 3. And after the next input, the output of the bot could be either 3 (length of the 'first' list) or 2 (the length of the 'second' list). I know my explanation is not the best, so please let me know if you need more details.

The bot is deployed on a free Heroku instance.

Attached to this post if my whole script, and a picture from the bot showing an example.

```
import os
from pymessenger.bot import Bot
from collections import defaultdict

import requests
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get('PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN')
bot = Bot(ACCESS_TOKEN)


a = defaultdict(list)


@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        output = request.get_json()
        for event in output['entry']:
            messaging = event['messaging']
            for x in messaging:
                if x.get('message'):
                    recipient_id = x['sender']['id']
                    a[recipient_id].append(1)
                    bot.send_text_message(recipient_id, len(a[recipient_id]))
    return 'Success'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: facebook's api posts back the message with the recipientID of the facebook page's ID. I know kinda weird. My guess is that you (user1) populates that list, but somewhere in between (user2 being the facebook page) also contributes to the length of the list.. idk, just a guess. what do you think? try printing out recipient IDs

Comment: I try printing the ID's and didn't saw anything unusual.